# Building a C Library using Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to write Bazel Build file for the following directory structure.

```
thirdparty
    |_WORKSPACE
    |_somelib
    |    |_src
    |         |_ a.c
    |         |_ BUILD
    |    |_include
    |         |_a.h
    |_include
       |_ b.h
```

The current BUILD file : thirdparty/somelib/src/BUILD

```
cc_library(
 name = "a",
 srcs = ["a.c"],
 hdrs = ["thirdparty/somelib/include/a.h"],
)
```

This build file is causing an error:

Command used: bazel build somelib/src:a

ERROR:/thirdparty/somelib/src/BUILD:1:1: no such package 'thirdparty/somelib/include/a.h': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//a/src:l

ERROR: Analysis of target '//somelib/src:a' failed; build aborted.

I need some help in figuring out where I went wrong with the BUILD File

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

There are many ways to fix this problem, one of them is:

1. Add a `BUILD` file to `somelib/include` with the contents:

   ```
   filegroup(
       name = "headers",
       srcs = ["a.h"],
       visibility = ["//somelib/src:__pkg__"],
   )
   ```
2. Update `somelib/src/BUILD` to read:

   ```
   cc_library(
       name = "a",
       srcs = ["a.c"],
       hdrs = ["//somelib/include:headers"],
   )
   ```
3. You can now build it with `bazel build //somelib/src:a`.

#### Alternative

Another solution would be to move `somelib/src/BUILD` to `somelib/BUILD`, so now the package is `//somelib` with two subdirectories, `src` and `include`, neither of them having their own BUILD file (so they are not packages themselves). You'd then update `somelib/BUILD` to look like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["src/a.c"],
    hdrs = ["include/a.h"],
)
```

and you'd build it like `bazel build //somelib:a`.

#### Explanation

See https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/build-ref.html#packages_targets

Comment: When I go ahead with the alternative solution, I'm hitting the following error,


somelib/src/a.c:1:25: fatal error: a.h: No such file or directory  
#include "a.h"
compilation terminated.

Comment: With the alternative solution, when I added copts =["-Isomelib/include"] it worked.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to solve the problem, another is to use workspace-relative #include, e.g. `#include "somelib/include/a.h"`.